# Loyalty Management API's "Get Ledger History" returns Resource Not Found

Tags: rest-api, api, integration, summer-23

This is the documentation of API call: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/connect_resources_transaction_ledger.htm

I am doing everything certainly by the book, yet this API returns this:

```
{
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
```

This API endpoint is fairly new, since it's been available since Summer 23 (v58). I am suspecting a mistake in the deployment of this API.

The SF test instance where I'm making this call is already on Summer 23 (v58)

Anyone managed to get successful response from that API?

Comment: Can you include the endpoint URI that you've tried with?

Comment: URI: https://<mydomain name>--<sandbox name>.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v58.0/connect/loyalty/programs/<loyalty program name>/members/<member number>/transaction-ledger-summary. I'm certain that URL params I've omitted aren't the cause because with them I can successfully call Member Details call of Loyalty Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document's `resource` is accurate - but, the `resource examples` are *inaccurate*. The URL should be

`/data/v58.0/loyalty/programs/...`

[image]

The follow-up examples show `/connect/` and appears to be what you tried. If you look at the other resources in LoyaltyManagement - you'll see the [other](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/connect_resources_enroll_corporate_member.htm) resources [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/connect_resources_enroll_individual_member.htm) does not include `/connect/` in the url path and I can see internally it does not have `/connect/` in it either.

Comment: Good catch. I confirm that by removing the "/connect" patch I got it to work. Thank you very much!
Edit: I'll try my best to let SF guys notice and correct this mistake in documentation.

Comment: And a side-note: I did not suspect "/connect" path at all because another similiar Loyalty API I was trying to call was this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.loyalty.meta/loyalty/connect_resources_transaction_history.htm which includes "/connect" path in it (and it actually works that way)